# Does charge carrier concentration vary with magnetic field (due to Hall effect)?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm writing up an experiment on the use of the Hall effect to determine charge carrier concentration for n-doped Germanium. Which initially led me to believe that the concentration is a constant for a given material. But looking at the results (a slight reduction in concentration with increasing B-field), I'm starting to wonder.

I would guess that as B field increases, more charge carriers are forced to the side of a conductor- but would that change the concentration?

All insights much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, of course the Hall effect does create a carrier concentration change.
But, the Hall effect only exists in non-equilibrium state, when a current is
flowing transverse to the magnetic field.

So, a bulk semiconductor ought not show a carrier density fluctuation due to B
field, but a current-carrying conductor is another story.   Actually,
every old TV tube reminds us that moving charge carriers, even in a vacuum, are forced to new
places (or trajectories) by a magnetic field.